# Can I use a godaddy domain with ESXI?

Tags: networking, dns, vmware

I just got my server set up with ESXI 6.5 and I'm still learning how to work with it. I can currently access it via the servers internal IP.

I have a domain with godaddy and I was wondering if I could assign a subdomain to the ESXI server.

Example: connect to the web GUI and via Fusion by typing "vm.domainnamehere.com".

Is this at all possible?

I tried editing the default TCP/IP stack and putting in hostname/domain name/dns myself but it just says "failed to update configuration". I'm not sure if this is the right place to add and what to type in the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Using DNS with ESXi it is possible, absolutely yes. But you want to use godaddy to add subdmain entry resolve the internal network address of your ESX? 
In conclusion, what you want to do is possible, but need more detail to understand better what you want realize.

Comment: I have a CNAME entry on the godaddy site named vm. The main A entry uses the external IP of my router which the server is connected to. Instead of going to http://192.168.0.107 in my browser I would like to be able to use http://vm.domainnamehere.com. This both from the internal network and outside of the network via port forwarding.

Comment: Like this you have to configure your router to forward the correct port (here you can fine a detailed list: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2039095) on the esx no more configuration are required, it should work also if have a different name #edit# for external network no problem, but for the internal you could add an entry on your hosts file or in to router DNS if the router permit you to do, like this (if you can add the entry in router DNS) from the local network you will resolve the name with internal address and from external world with the public one